# Regular expression for US phone number not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

This type of questions are asked so many times on SO but i am having problem with expression and its not working for me.

I need to allow only numbers,(,),- in phone number and for that i have code as follows.
But only uncommented expression is working and that is for only numbers no (,),- are allowed and i searched and got other expressions which should allow (,),-  but those are not working too.

What could be wrong?
Example: `9876545678, (123) 123-7657`

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        if(textField == aTfdPhone)
        {
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
                    return NO;
                 }
             NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

             NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9])?)?$";
    //       NSString *expression = @"^[(]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[)]?[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}$";
       //      NSString * const expression = @"^([+-]{1})([0-9]{3})$";
             NSError *error = nil;

             NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression 
                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                         error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error %@", error);
            }
            NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                       options:0
                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
            if (numberOfMatches == 0){
                    return NO;
             }
        }
        return TRUE; 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Check this out - http://snipplr.com/view/7622/

Comment: None of your attempts resemble your stated requirements. The first commented-out one restricts the allowed numbers, and has very specific and rigid grouping requirements, but otherwise looks close to what you say you want. But especially if regular expressions are totally alien to you, you should consider a different approach. A common suggestion is to trim all whitespace and punctuation, then check that you have only numbers, and a sufficiently long sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt fails to recognize `(123) 123-7657` because of the first digit:

It should be

```
   NSString *expression = @"^[(]?[1-9][0-9]{2}[)]?[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}$";
```

not

```
   NSString *expression = @"^[(]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[)]?[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}$";
```

The only difference is the operator matching the first digit `[2-9]` would not match 1.

Comment: This expression not allowing even numbers too